# What's the song that plays during the basketball scene in episode 2 of Parasyte?

Tags: music, parasyte

The song starts playing from around 3:12 (when Shin'ichi walked to school) to around 4:53 (at the end of the basketball game). I just really like the music during that scene.

Comment: If you know at what time in the episode this scene occurs, it might help you get a response faster if you include that in your question.

Answer (score 1):

The music is written by [Ken Arai](http://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E5%AF%84%E7%94%9F%E7%8D%A3#.E3.82.B9.E3.82.BF.E3.83.83.E3.83.95).

The soundtrack track listing is [here](http://www.vap.co.jp/goods/1413348048571/) (or [here on Amazon.co.jp](http://www.amazon.co.jp/dp/B00ONY5W66)), where you can listen to samples of each track to check which song you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

If you mean [this OST](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cA3PSYeo7rs&t=2m35s), then title is ***Lesson1*** by Ken Arai.